# POST request returning 401 Unauthorised (only in Chrome)

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-rest-framework, axios, http-headers

I'm using Django Rest Framework and Vue.js to build a basic web app, and am currently working on the auth. Using axios to send a post request while registering a new user returns 401 in Chrome for some reason, but works in other browsers (Edge) and returns a 201 Created.

The error in chrome is "detail: Invalid Token", but this particular endpoint (registration) doesn't even need auth/token to access.

My frontend is at http://192.168.1.33:8080 and my backend is at http://127.0.0.1:8000
I am trying to POST data to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/auths/

The Network tab in chrome dev tools after trying a request:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/auths/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.33:8080
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 27
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 12:19:15 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.5
Vary: Accept, Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Token
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Token acf8b9099de5eba413dea141ce2c06b6cfb03159
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 53
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: http://192.168.1.33:8080
Referer: http://192.168.1.33:8080/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
```

The network tab in Edge dev tools after trying the same thing:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/auths/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 201 Created
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.33:8080
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 12:20:25 GMT
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/auths/12/
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.5
Vary: Accept, Origin, Cookie
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: http://192.168.1.33:8080
Referer: http://192.168.1.33:8080/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Microsoft Edge";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.43
```

The obvious difference is that there is a "WWW-Authenticate: Token" in the Chrome Network tab, which is odd.

CORS headers and all have been set up properly, plus the issue is only in Chrome. Is this some Chrome quirk, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that, after spending some two hours on a problem, you only get the answer *after* you've posted it on a forum? Probably something to do with putting the problem down categorically and formally...

Anyway. Turns out the issue was with there being a random token sitting in Chrome's local storage, which was causing all the trouble with the "invalid" token. I cleared local storage, and it's working now. No clue why I had to do this specifically — I had made sure to clear the cache earlier...